# How can I see my own Candidate Score?

Tags: support, election

On the election nomination page, below each person's nomination text, there's a grey box that gives a summary of their activity on the site, and a Candidate Score.

How can I see my own candidate score?

[image]

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253781/133299

Answer (score 2):

I was curious what my own score was, and from another election in progress I knew that there's a Stack Exchange Data Explorer query that will show it.  To find your own score, first go to your profile and note your userid in the url.  For example, my ID is 266:

> https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/266/ward

Then go to this SEDE query:

http://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=33128%2C7561%2C20183%2C266

Scroll down to where it says Enter Parameters / UserIDs, delete 266 (my ID) and enter your own, then click Run Query.

[image]

It will ask you for a captcha, then show you a table with your score along with the scores of the current (as of 28 Jan 2016) nominated users.